# How the tailmap method get the sortedmap from the input treemap?

Tags: java

The treemap has a method, tailmap to get a sortedmap which the key no less than the fromkey.
After trace the source code, I found the tailmap finish the work in the constuct method of NavigableSubMap.
here is the code.

```
NavigableSubMap(TreeMap<K,V> m,
                        boolean fromStart, K lo, boolean loInclusive,
                        boolean toEnd,     K hi, boolean hiInclusive) {
            if (!fromStart && !toEnd) {
                if (m.compare(lo, hi) > 0)
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("fromKey > toKey");
            } else {
                if (!fromStart) // type check
                    m.compare(lo, lo);
                if (!toEnd)
                    m.compare(hi, hi);
            }

            this.m = m;
            this.fromStart = fromStart;
            this.lo = lo;
            this.loInclusive = loInclusive;
            this.toEnd = toEnd;
            this.hi = hi;
            this.hiInclusive = hiInclusive;
        }
```

after the step of this.toEnd = toEnd; the NavigableSubMap class has the tailed map. 
how it finished this?

Comment: What do you mean, "how it finished this"?  What's the part you don't understand?